# receiveing "550 data channel timed out" while using python storbinary

Tags: python

I am trying to upload files from a UNIX server to a windows server using python FTP_TLS. Here is my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftps = FTP_TLS('server')
ftps.connect(port=myport)
ftps.login('user', 'password')           
ftps.prot_p()          
ftps.retrlines('LIST')
remote_path = "MYremotePath"
ftps.cwd(remote_path)
ftps.storbinary('STOR myfile.txt', open('myfile.txt', 'rb'))
myfile.close()
ftps.close()
```

I can connect to the server successfully and receive the list of files, but I am not able able to upload the file and after some time I receive the following error:

```
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Data channel timed out due to not meeting the minimum bandwidth requirement.
```

I should mention that I am able to upload files on the same server using perl FTPSSL library. The problem happens only in python.
Does anyone have any idea about how to resolve this issue?
Thanks